# Displaying some fields of other table rows within one field of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview, tableadapter

I have two tables A and B. B has a column C with integer values. For one row in A there can be more rows in B. The rows of B are related to elements of A with the primary index of A. Now I want to display in a `DataGridView` of A in a column all values C which are related to the row of A.
Example:
Table A has rows with key 1, 2, 3
Table B has rows A(1), B(1), C(2), D(2), E(2), F(3) where ABC is the integer value and (x) is the key relation. So the `DataGridView` should look like:

```
A_Row1Col1Value, A_Row1Col2Value, B_"A; B"
A_Row2Col2Value, A_Row2Col2Value, B_"C; D; E"
A_Row3Col1Value, A_Row3Col2Value, B_"F"
```

whereby instead of ';' another separator character could also be used.

Could this be solved with the SQL-`SELECT` of the `TableAdapter`?

Comment: This would be messy to accomplish in SQL since you're looking to concatenate.  I would explore, if you're not dealing with a ton of data, handling this through code.. i.e.: run query for table A and B, loop through A finding values in col C of table B and creating the field.

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used. Some have nice SQL intrinsic function to accomplish record concatenation. Research STRING_AGG function.

Comment: Thank's a lot. In meantime I programmed that according hint of MX313 by using the virtual mode of the DataGridView. Maybe I find a future use case for the STRING_AGG function.